# PDF anexado em email chega codificado

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Estou anexando um PDF para enviar no email, usando Laravel e DOMPDF
mas quando chega o email, não tem anexo em pdf, ele chega codificado no corpo do email. segue o código.

Lembrando que o PDF é gerado 100%. consigo ver ele pelo browser. mas envia assim no email

```
public function enviarEmail(Request $request, $id)
{
    $orcamento = $this->orcamentosService->exibir($id);

    $data["email"]          = $request->get("email");
    $data["client_name"]    = $request->get($orcamento->cliente->nome);
    $data["subject"]        = $request->get("assunto");

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('paginas.orcamentos.imprimir', ['orcamento' => $orcamento])->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');

    try{
        Mail::send('emails.orcamento', $data, function($message)use($data,$pdf) {
            $message->to($data["email"], $data["client_name"])
                ->from('xxx')
                ->subject($data["subject"])
                ->attachData($pdf->output(), "orcamento.pdf", ['mime' => 'application/pdf']);
        });
    }catch(JWTException $exception){
        $this->serverstatuscode = "0";
        $this->serverstatusdes = $exception->getMessage();
    }
    if (Mail::failures()) {
        $this->statusdesc  =   "Erro ao enviar e-mail";
        $this->statuscode  =   "0";

    }else{

        $this->statusdesc  =   "Email enviado com sucesso";
        $this->statuscode  =   "1";
    }
    return response()->json(compact('this'));
}
```

E aqui como o PDF chega no email

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O método `$pdf->output()` gera o conteudo binário do arquivo PDF, já o método `attach()` precisa de um arquivo físico para ser enviado, então eu te recomentdo salvar este conteúdo temporariamente:

```
Storage::put('temp/mail.pdf', $pdf->output());
```

E enviar este arquivo salvo por email:

```
->attach(Storage::get('temp/mail.pdf'));
```

E após o envio remover o arquivo temporário para não encher seu *HD*:

```
Storage::delete('temp/mail.pdf')
```

Comment: Na verdade o método attachData() não precisa de um arquivo gerado no HD, ele usa arquivo gerado na memoria, que é oque estou fazendo.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#attachments. Creio que o problema seja outro, parece não estar renderizando o PDF.

Comment: Já experimentou então usar um metodo que extente o `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` para fazer o envio no lugar de usar diretamente a classe `Mail` ?

Comment: nossa mano.. depois de muito sofrer.. descobri o problema.. se o corpo do email estiver vazio, ele enfia o arquivo dentro do corpo do email, por isso não chegava como anexo. era inserido no corpo do email..

Answer (score 0):

attachData método pode ser usado para anexar uma sequência bruta de bytes como um anexo. Por exemplo, você pode usar esse método se tiver gerado um PDF na memória e quiser anexá-lo ao e-mail sem gravá-lo no disco. O attachData método aceita os bytes de dados brutos como seu primeiro argumento, o nome do arquivo como seu segundo argumento e um array de opções como seu terceiro argumento:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->attachData($this->pdf, 'name.pdf', [
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);
}
```